# Creating columns with hierarchal relationship to each other from two original columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am working on this project and I need to create columns with hierarchal relationship to each other in pandas based on the original two columns that indicates hierarchal relationships of each value.

|  | supervisory_org | Superior_org |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | org_2 | org_1 |
| 1 | org_7 | org_3 |
| 2 | org_4 | org_2 |
| 3 | org_6 | org_3 |
| 4 | org_9 | org_5 |
| 5 | org_3 | org_1 |
| 6 | org_5 | org_3 |
| 7 | org_8 | org_5 |

Above are the two original columns that indicates the relationship between two organizations(values). I want to make those hierarchal relationship between orgs more visible by spreading across multiple columns as below. (Below is the desired output)

|  | Level_1 | Level_2 | Level_3 | Level_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | org_1 | org_2 | org_4 | NaN |
| 1 | org_1 | org_3 | org_6 | NaN |
| 2 | org_1 | org_3 | org_7 | NaN |
| 3 | org_1 | org_3 | org_5 | org_8 |
| 4 | org_1 | org_3 | org_5 | org_9 |

I'm trying to make this work in pandas but still haven't come up with a way to do it. Anyone have any suggestions on how to approach this problems?

This is the code for creating the first table

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"supervisory_org" : ["org_2","org_7" ,"org_4", "org_6","org_9","org_3","org_5", "org_8"],
                   "Superior_org" : ["org_1","org_3","org_2","org_3","org_5","org_1","org_3","org_5"]})
```

Comment: Show what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find the roots (those with no org over them)
2. Use merge iteratively to match superior -> zero or more next rank orgs

The usual merge behavior with matching one to many ensures we duplicate rows for superior orgs as appropriate when needed.

We rename and remove columns as needed in the loop to handle the iterated merge.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"supervisory_org" : ["org_2","org_7" ,"org_4", "org_6","org_9","org_3","org_5", "org_8"],
                   "Superior_org" : ["org_1","org_3","org_2","org_3","org_5","org_1","org_3","org_5"]})
```

```
# Find the roots - orgs without superiors
roots = (pd.Index(df['Superior_org'].unique()).difference(df['supervisory_org'])
         .to_series()
         .rename("Level_1")
        )
roots
```

```
org_1    org_1
Name: Level_1, dtype: object
```

```
# Use merge to find those ranked just below their superiors

result = roots
upper_col = "Superior_org"
lower_col = 'supervisory_org'
for index in range(1, 100):
    result = pd.merge(result, df,
                      left_on=f"Level_{index}",
                      right_on=upper_col,
                      how="left")
    result.pop(upper_col)
    # if there are no more lower levels, done
    if result[lower_col].isna().all():
        result.pop(lower_col)
        break
    result = result.rename(columns={lower_col: f'Level_{index + 1}'})
    
result
```

```
  Level_1 Level_2 Level_3 Level_4
0   org_1   org_2   org_4     NaN
1   org_1   org_3   org_7     NaN
2   org_1   org_3   org_6     NaN
3   org_1   org_3   org_5   org_9
4   org_1   org_3   org_5   org_8
```

#### Sorting

The sorting rule apparent from your example is first by depth, then alphabethical.

So we can compute the depth, then sort, and remove the depth column.

```
result.insert(0, 'depth', result.notna().sum(axis=1))

result = (result.sort_values(by=list(result.columns), ignore_index=True)
          .drop(columns='depth')
         )
result
```

```
  Level_1 Level_2 Level_3 Level_4
0   org_1   org_2   org_4     NaN
1   org_1   org_3   org_6     NaN
2   org_1   org_3   org_7     NaN
3   org_1   org_3   org_5   org_8
4   org_1   org_3   org_5   org_9
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I was in a hurry and found a way to do it with treelib. Appreciate you tho!